# How to implement android RESTful client with Robospice (or something like this) + OAuth?

Tags: android, rest, oauth, robospice

How to implement Robospice (or something like this) + OAuth?

Maybe someone can share link to examples of good practices for creating RESTful android clients? I can't figure the architecture of RESTful app with OAuth, which cover all problems with activity's lifecycle.
Of course I know about Virgil Dobjanschi "Google I/O 2010 - Android REST client applications". With some Libraries like Robospice it is very easy to implement. But what if app uses OAuth for authorization to service? What libraries for OAuth could be useful? where store access token? How execute some requests synchronously? etc. ...

I am looking for complete code examples or at least advices about design and architecture.

Comment: Check this link https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. Are you talking about OAuth 1 or OAuth 2? For the former, you could use [signpost](https://github.com/mttkay/signpost). For the latter, you could use RoboSpice + Google Http Client + [Google OAuth Client Library](https://github.com/google/google-oauth-java-client).

If you use Google Http Client as your network library, what you need to do is to create your own `HttpClientSpiceService` based on `GoogleHttpClientSpiceService`, which you can find in RoboSpice. Then, you need something like this:

```
public static HttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory() {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
    return httpTransport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        @Override
        public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
            // TODO: authorize or sign request...
            // Note that this will authorize/sign ALL the requests you make,
            // so you will probably want to improve on that.
        }
    });
}
```

The rest is really up to you, but the basics are to implement a way to provide third-party log-in, get the required token and set up the OAuth library of your choice.